# I want my name to be removed from a patent

Tags: legal, troll, remove, contract, agreement

In contrast to common public questions on this website, this time I myself want my name to be removed from a patent because I had zero contribution to the patent. If the company doesn’t agree to remove my name, I can take legal action, right? Because long story short, the company is already trying to troll me via this patent. I can give you more details (1) if you are interested.
Thank you.
(1) Unfortunately, in my work contract, it reads "The employee undertakes to assist the Company, if the Company wishes so, on enabling the Company to protect, register, maintain and fully utilize the materials, results and intellectual property rights described in Section 10.1"
Based on this clause, the Company wants to extend the borders of the patent beyond imaginable by pushing me to sign a new agreement. I already left the company by the way.

Comment: Are others listed as inventors and  do you agree that they are inventors ?  By trolling you do you just mean they are pestering you to sign things ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer. I believe that listing a non-inventor as an inventor on a patent application risks the validity of the resultant patent. You can inform your previous company that you will inform the USPTO that a non-inventor is being listed on the application. There are other mechanisms for someone to challenge the grant of a patent but I won't get into those.

I'm not sure what "troll me via this patent" means. However you are not now an employee so I don't see how a document that requires employees to do something applies. I also don't see why you should be required to sign anything new. However, I'm not a lawyer and I don't have access to the documents you've signed.

I would, respectfully, remind the company that you did not contribute conceptionally to the invention and thus should not be listed as an inventor. If you know who should be listed as an inventor suggest them. This is one of those situations where a letter from a lawyer might have more impact. **The main point is to stay civil and professional.** Let them know you are helping them achieve their goal of obtaining a patent by not having a non-inventor improperly listed. You may want to remind them it is within you power to make the USPTO aware of a discrepancy in the listed inventors.

If, however, you are just mad at the company and you did actually contribute something that is reflected in a claim on the patent application, I would simply sign the documents and allow them to list you. I don't see how this hurts you. Most people are happy to have themselves listed as an inventor on a patent. As for whether the patent is extended beyond the borders of the imaginable, it is the patent examiners job, not yours, to keep this from happening. Many patent applications shoot for the moon with their initial claims and end up with narrower ones in the end.